# Abnormality in android fragment animation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a YouTube style UI for my app. 
I have two Fragment.. lets say A(left) and B(right). On clicking the app icon in the Action bar, B should slides to the right. On clicking again, it should slides back to the left. 
I have a Listview on B and A is empty. Also, I am using ActionBarSherlock.

The following behaviour is experienced:
1. When App icon clicked,
B slides to the right normally

1. When App icon is clicked again
   B slides to the left normally
2. When App icon is clicked again 
   B doesnt slide unless the fragment is touched manually.

On subsequent clicks, B slides to left normally. But it slides to the right only when touched after clicking the button.
what could be the issue and how can i solve it? Thank you.

Comment: In other words i want to say that my Fragment B is losing focus and thus does not respond to the startAnimation().. what can  be done?

Comment: when i have a TextView on B, the animation doesnt work